# Stored procedure doesn't execute from a web service, but does in SSMS

Tags: c#, sql, web-services, stored-procedures, permissions

I have connection issue with sql server management studio(SSMS), when connecting through a web service.

If I login with account xxx in SSMS, I can execute a stored procedure. The permissions for this user xxx on the stored procedure, as well as all of the tables that this stored procedure use, are Alter, control, execute, references, take ownership, and view definition. All I think I need is execute. No problem there, the stored procedure runs fine.

Then, in my web service, I have it set up to run this stored procedure. I run it using javascript, and SOAP. It returns an error. I have tested it, and without a doubt, the service code is correct, as well as the javascript. I believe the problem is the permissions, or some configuration in sql. But I can't figure out why connecting to sql through a web service with an account that works doesn't let me run this stored procedure.

Is there something I am missing about sql permissions, like when not using SSMS. Or, is there some way I can test the connection from my web service, which is in C#?

Here is some code that shows how I have it all linked up.

Web Service Connection (C#):

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="TABLE_NAME" connectionString="Data Source=db_name\instance1;Connect Timeout=30;Initial Catalog=TABLE_NAME;User ID=xxx;PWD=****" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Web Service Code (C#):

```
[WebMethod]
public System.Data.DataSet FindThings(string params){
RegistrationDB RegDB = new RegistrationDB();
return RegDB.FindThings(connectionstring, DBHelper.Providers.SqlServer, params);
}

public DataSet FindThings(string connectString, DBHelper.Providers provider, string params){
  DBHelper db = new DBHelper();
  db.CreateDBObjects(connectString, provider);
  DataSet ds;
  try{
    db.AddParameter("@parameters", params);
    ds = db.GetDataSet("[dbo].[procedure_name]", CommandType.StoredProcedure, ConnectionState.Open);
    ds.Tables[0].TableName = "Things";
    ds.Tables[1].TableName = "YearParameters";
  }
  finally{
    db.connection.Close();
  }
  return ds;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var webServiceUrl = "/test.asmx";
var soapEnv = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
  <soapenv:Body> \
    <FindThings  xmlns='http://tempuri.org/'> \
      <params>" + varParams + "</params> \
    </FindThings> \
  </soapenv:Body> \
</soapenv:Envelope>";

$.ajax({
    url: webServiceUrl,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "xml",
    data: soapEnv,
    complete: getResult,
    contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
});

function getResult(result, status) {
  if(status != "success"){
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += "<p>Status: " + status + "</p>";
  }
}
```

So this is where I get the output "Status: error", on the webpage.

Anyone know how I should go about fixing this?

Comment: Does your user have access to log in to the server remotely?

Comment: Can you wrap all server-code in try-catch and log error with stach trace to file, or just watch it in the debug mode?

Comment: Not sure about remote login, will check. As for debugging in c#, I am not sure if I can do this, as the web service needs to be deployed into a different location from where the solution is stored.

Comment: If you can't debug, could you not add a catch block into your webservice to write to a file the exception, or go straight to your .asmx page and call the method from their, at least then the specific SQL error will be written to the webpage (depending on your settings but these should be easy enough to change)

Comment: Edit- As far as I can tell, remote login access is enabled for all users. I will try to debug with a catch, that is a good idea. As for testing directly from the .asmx, on that page under Test is the message "The test form is only available for requests from the local machine."

Comment: I went to the local server and did a test directly from the asmx page. I got a 500 internal server error.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the SQL Server you could also look at the logged events there or run a Profiler trace.  It could be that the user you think is being used to connect to SQL server is not on your deployment machine.  Getting the debug information through try/catch is a good solution, just giving you another alternative.

Comment: Hi. I am not the db admin for this server, so I don't think I have access to logged events. I'm not sure what you mean by deployment machine. I can definitely login with the user to the right server using SSMS. Also, I have checked the permissions several times, and they seem to be correct. Effective permissions look to be on execute.

Comment: Update: I was using fiddler while I did a test of the web service from the .asmx web page. I have found this error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." I will update with further finds/fixes.

Comment: So what I've found is that, basically I am getting nothing back from the DbDataAdapter object, when it does the Fill method. Basically, either my connection is wrong, my data is wrong, or the database isn't letting the user run the query. I still don't get it, because I had the exact same code working, but on a different database. Now, I have the stored procedure onto this new database, and the user I'm using to connect with has execute permissions, but it doesn't work. I will have to recheck if the user can login remotely I guess, or check the database for configuration differences.

Answer (score 0):

This might because your service account has been deleted. Check this. I have met the same issue before.

Comment: You forgot to add the link to your answer.